# Appache web server won't start

Tags: apache

i have problem with xampp server. The Apache web server won't start (never green light )...my OS is Ubuntu 18.04 and i use symfony in this OS (maybe the problem is symfony) 
I tried many solution and they not work 
I tried :
sudo apachectl stop

Comment: Did you look at logs? There should be clear error message re why Apache can't start. Probably some misconfiguration, like typo in config file.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/.  Plenty of tutorials and help pages on that subject.  Logs are key.  `apachectl -t` is also good to try, to ensure your configuration is valid.  Can't help without details.

Comment: That looks more like a question for https://serverfault.com/ anyway, as long as it's a bit more detailed, as it doesn't seem there's any programming languages involved here.